# Can a UA Unity Domain cleric use Channel Divinity: Shared Burden as a reaction when the cleric takes damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, unearthed-arcana, reactions

I’m currently working on a Unity Domain cleric build, and I believe the wording of the ability Shared Burden is intended to be different than the RAW wording.

The description of the Unity Domain cleric's [Channel Divinity: Shared Burden](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_02_06_Subclasses2.pdf#page=3) feature (from [Unearthed Arcana 2020: Subclasses Part 2](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_02_06_Subclasses2.pdf)) says:

> When **a creature you can see within 30 feet of you** takes damage,
> you can use your reaction to choose a number of other willing
> creatures you can see, up to a number of creatures equal to your
> Wisdom modifier (minimum of one creature). Distribute the damage taken
> between the original target and the chosen creatures. Each creature
> must take at least 1 damage. Apply any damage resistance or
> vulnerability of the creatures involved after you distribute the
> damage.

It says a creature you can *see* within 30 feet of *you*. It doesn’t specify "another creature", so based on my interpretation you can use this on yourself.

Is my interpretation correct? Can a Unity Domain cleric use Channel Divinity: Shared Burden as a reaction when the cleric takes damage?

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, you can target yourself

Since you are a creature you can see, you would be able to react to taking damage yourself to distribute that damage among your allies.

Compare this to something like *[healing word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word)*, which can be used to target yourself:

> **A creature of your choice that you can see within range** regains hit points equal to 1d4 + your spellcasting ability modifier.

Although Channel Divinity isn't a spell, I believe it would still use the same targeting rules as spells; those rules on targeting say:

> **[Targeting Yourself](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#TargetingYourself)**
> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other than you.